# Send email with Amazon SES using smtp java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to use exactly same code as here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html I changed `FROM, FROMNAME, TO, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD, HOST` . But I am not able to send email. Both the email has been added and verified for Amazon SES.

I am using mail dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Logs:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.1
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/C:/Users/ranjans/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.10.5.1/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.10.5.1.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/C:/Users/ranjans/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ses/1.10.5.1/aws-java-sdk-ses-1.10.5.1.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,aws,com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport,Amazon Web Services LLC]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], aws=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,aws,com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AWSJavaMailTransport,Amazon Web Services LLC]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
Sending...
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", port 587, isSSL false
The email was not sent.
Error message: Couldn't connect to host, port: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, 587; timeout -1
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: check your AWS port and the server information by login into your SES in left hand side SMTP settings and check the credentials too.

Comment: Are you providing username/password correctly?

Comment: Usually, username is SES Key and password is SES Secret.

Comment: I re-verified SES username, password as well as port. No luck! Post SES configuration I got one email with SES details with credential. I am using that only.

Comment: see my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807882/6414086

Answer (score 0):

> trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", port **587**, isSSL **false**
>
> The email was not sent.

You should try port 25, if isSSL=false or make SSL=true and use ssl port.

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall / anti-virus settings.