# How do you provide AWS keys to Amazon SES service when sending emails?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

The documentation says you need a 'shared credentials file' in your home directory, but that's not going to work for production! So how do you specify the AWS keys when sending an email? It doesn't give any examples!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-using-sdk.html

> This code example assumes that you have installed the AWS SDK for Java, and that you have created a shared credentials file.

```
  AmazonSimpleEmailService client = 
      AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
      ...
  client.sendEmail(request);
```

Their reference documentation doesn't even contain the `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder`!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-guide&searchQuery=AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder&x=3&y=8&this_doc_product=Amazon+Simple+Email+Service&this_doc_guide=API+Reference&doc_locale=en_us#facet_doc_product=Amazon%20Simple%20Email%20Service&facet_doc_guide=API%20Reference

Comment: I don't see where it says that you 'need' to do that. It provides an example that uses one way, of numerous ways, to provide credentials. Assuming that you're using EC2 or Lambda, use IAM roles. Also see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html

Comment: @jarmod What are the numerous ways? Can you give an example? I am using IAM roles, but it still uses an AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and secret. I am using Elastic Beanstalk, and the environment doesn't work in EB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664938/how-do-i-pass-aws-access-key-id-for-amazon-ses-on-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: When using IAM roles on EC2, credentials are retrieved from a metadata service, not from environment variables. A discussion of the numerous options for providing credentials to Elastic Beanstalk can be found at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-specify-credentials.html

Comment: see my answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807882/6414086

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using EC2 or Lambda or any [AWS IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#create-iam-role) supported service, secured way is to go with creating a role which have access to SES and attach it to the resource. You will not need to maintain any credentials.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#create-iam-role

Following link provides different ways to provide credentials to your java program
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

If you want to give within your program

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
    @Override
    public void refresh() {}
        @Override
        public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
        return new AWSCredentials() {
            @Override
            public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                return "YOUR_SECRET_KEY";
            }
            @Override
            public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                return "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY";
            }
        };
    }
};

AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider).build();
```

Comment: "Environment variables – AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"

Comment: Scratch that. Elastic Beanstalk doesn't set environment for Spring Boot/Tomcat. It sets Java properties. So: "Java system properties – `aws.accessKeyId` and `aws.secretKey`. The AWS SDK for Java uses the SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider to load these credentials."