# How do I pass AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID for Amazon SES on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ses

I set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as environment variables in my local computer and it works fine. When I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, I set the "Environment properties", but they are passed as `-D` Java system properties, not set as environment variables, and it generates an error.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console

> while the Tomcat platform sets Java system properties that you retrieve with System.getProperty.

#### Error

> 2018-08-03 02:34:37.001  INFO 32073 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.s.xxxxx.apis.XxxxxxxApiController  : The email was not sent. Error: User 'arn:aws:sts::849611986161:assumed-role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role/i-0f447c52c84e1fd93' is not authorized to perform 'ses:SendEmail' on resource 'arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:849611986161:identity/xxxxxx@xxxxx.com' (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: c3835dda-96c5-11e8-8a21-67774160691b)

Amazon SES is expecting environment variables only (or a 'shared credential file' in your home directory). So how do I pass AWS keys to Amazon SES in Elastic Beanstalk for a Java Spring Boot application using the environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSM(Systems Manager Service) parameter store to keep your environment variables and access it through any service which has IAM permissions. In this scenario since you need Access Keys, it doesn't need any of the environment variables to be kept. You can just use your Instance Profile inside elastic beanstalk and it will provide you the access key and secret access key of your assigned IAM for the elastic beanstalk. Please refer this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default

> Java system properties–aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey. The AWS SDK for Java uses the SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider to load these credentials.

So instead of `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, set `aws.accessKeyId`, which is then set as a Java system property on the command line, which is picked up by Amazon SES SDK.